# Adding Blur Filter to The Stage in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

[image]

Is it possible to add like a "global blur" filter to the stage via ActionScript 3 ?

Below is my code attempt but it obviously doesn't make sense to Flash :

```
stage.filters = [myBlur];
```

Extending my question, I would love to know if it is possible to programmatically apply said filter to a defined position of the stage.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Stage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html) object did not have a `filters` property, so `stage.filters = [myBlur];` will never work and will fire an error.

What you need here is to set your main timeline's `filters` property, like this :

```
root.filters = [myBlur];
```

or

```
this.filters = [myBlur];
```

or simply

```
filters = [myBlur];
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: It's almost close to what I want except that it blurs the whole stage along with its children movie clips but I would like it to blur an area of the stage excluding the movie clip  on whose timeline the code is placed in more or less the scenario is that when a button is clicked to show a menu, everything on stage is blurred except the menu. I don't know if you get my drift

Comment: @SoloWalker For that, you can for example (if it's possible) to put all those objects inside one container on which you'll apply the filter, you can also use a `BitmapData` to take a snapshot of your main timeline, apply your filter to a `Bitmap` using that `BitmapData` and then add it to the display list of the stage (or to a (new) `DisplayObject` in the stage) then you can show (add) your menu ...

Comment: Sorry i'm still pulling my weight in action script, still a bit of a novice so if you could please type out a sample code for me in relation to the `BitmapData` solution  or integrate it into this code:  `function toggleMenu(e:Event):void {
    
      if(switchbd.x <= 278){
          hideMenu();
   }else{
        showMenu();
    }
}

function showMenu():void {
    switchbd.gotoAndStop(2);

     switchbd_btn.filters = [ONf];

}

function hideMenu():void {
     switchbd_btn.filters = [OFf];`